# kml hotlink fails upon GE restart

Tags: kml, hotlinking

The following kml code creates a hotlink in a placemark balloon to a photo file using a relative reference. It works properly when first opened in GE (i.e., clicking on the hotlink causes the photo to appear).  But if GE is closed and then reopened, the hotlink no longer works.  What is causing this?

`<a href="PhotoDatabase/PhotoFileName.jpg">PhotoName</a>`

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

When you view the KML as it was first opened in GE, the link is relative to the original location of the KML file from which the JPEG is resolved. When you exit Google Earth and reopen, the KML is now part of the saved places file in for example the location "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Google\GoogleEarth\myplaces.kml".

The location of your saved places can be found here:
https://support.google.com/earth/answer/166438?hl=en

To fix this, you need to move the JPEG image to the same directory as the saved places KML file or change relative link to an absolute URL.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense, and explains the change in behavior since I changed to relative links from absolute.  As an alternative to your solution, is there a way to direct Google Earth to place the myplaces.kml in the directory currently containing my image files?  My objective is to make it easy to transfer the image files and kml file together to another computer - without having to recreate a specific directory structure in order for it to work.

Comment: Consider packing the images inside a KMZ file and use relative links from KML to those images.